# Can Mickey Mouse divide by $7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

In the figure displayed in the image below :

[image: divisibility by 7]

To find the remainder on dividing a number by $7$, start at node $0$, for each digit $D$ of the number, move along $D$ black arrows (for digit $0$ do not move at all), and as you pass from one digit to the next, move along a single white arrow.

For example, let $n = 325$. Start at node $0$, move along $3$ black arrows (to node $3$), then $1$ white arrow (to node $2$), then $2$ black arrows (to node $4$), then $1$ white arrow (to node $5$), and finally $5$ black arrows (to node $3$). Finishing at node $3$ shows that the remainder on dividing $325$ by $7$ is $3$.

If you try this for a number that is divisible by $7$, say $63$, you will always end up in node $0$. Therefore, it can also be used to test divisibility by $7$. In case while traversing the digits of number $n$, you end up in the node $0$, $n$ is divisible by $7$, else not.

What exactly is the mathematical explanation for this? Are there  such type of graphs for any other integer(s) too?

Comment: I think this is basically a graphical representation of doing calculations modulo $7$. If your number is $1a$, ($a$ arbitrary), then you can think of this as $10+a$ which when doing modular arithmetic would be the same as $3+a$, so go to $3$, then move $a$ numbers on the circle. Apply this logic throughout. You can inductively argue that this works in general, it's sufficient to check it for two digit numbers.

Comment: Where did you find this actually, just out of curiosity?

Comment: A [nice video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qhbuKbxJsk8) to a related topic=)

Comment: @snulty I saw the figure in a math blog and modified it a bit to make it look like a Mickey Mouse just for some fun.

Comment: It's actually fairly funny! I like the idea :) any other ideas for characters when working modulo a different number? :)

Comment: +1 but on my screen both arrows look grey!

Comment: All the "black" arrows lie on the "circle" of the face and are all anticlockwise in direction, the rest of the arrows (along the ears and nose of the face) are lighter/white in color in color. Thats one way to differentiate between the black and white arrows.

Comment: @snulty currently i dont have any other  character-depiction for the modulo of a different number but would update as soon as i hit upon an idea...

Comment: @flawr : the video is simply stunning!!

Comment: @flawr : any idea what software might have been used in the video to generate these graphs?

Comment: @naveendankal I have no idea, but it probably doesn't take much more than a few lines of code in any language with image processing capabilities.

Comment: number of Paths in graph will determine the modulo and weightage of nodes would be remainder.

Comment: @snulty : my latest question contains an image of an earthen lamp used on Diwali festival. I thought it could be used as mod 3 graph. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1989987/happy-div-aali-mod-3-graph

Comment: Are they like the flames on the lamp? It's fairly creative :)

Comment: Thanks, Yes they are flames of the lamp.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Such graphs exist for any (non-zero) integer.  In fact, the arrows reflect two basic operations $\bmod 7$:

- The black arrows represent adding one (note that they go up from $0$ to $6$ and then cyclically back to $0$ again)
- Similarly, the white arrows represent multiplication by $10$; note that $5$ goes to $1$, and this reflects the fact that $5\times10=50\equiv 1\pmod 7$.

Any given number can be written as a combination of these two operations on a starting value of zero; for instance, your example $N=325$ is equivalent to starting with zero, adding $1$ three times (giving $3$), multiplying by $10$ (giving $30$), adding $1$ twice more (giving $32$), multiplying by $10$ again (giving $320$), and then adding $1$ five more times (giving $325$). The graph just represents these operations $\bmod 7$, and so if you end up at node zero it means that your original number was a multiple of 7; this works because both the operations of adding one and multiplying by ten 'commute' through the mod-7 operation (i.e., $(n+1)\bmod 7$ $\equiv (n\bmod 7)+1\pmod 7$ and $(n\times10)\bmod 7$ $\equiv (n\bmod 7)\times 10\pmod 7$ ).  Since the individual operations commute with the mod operation, so will any combination of them.

But there's nothing special about $7$ here, and in fact that's enough to understand how to construct the graph for any base $b$: number a set of $b$ nodes from $0$ to $b-1$, and then construct a black arrow from $i$ to $i+1\pmod b$ for every node $i$, and a white arrow from $j$ to $j\times10\pmod b$ for every node $j$.  This will give the analogue of the 'Mickey Mouse' graph for that base.