# Happy Div-aali mod 3 graph

Tags: elementary-number-theory, graph-theory, divisibility

Diwali, the festival of light celebrated across the world,  is falling on 30th/10 this year, and  I tried a way to link up the date part (3 of 30) and the celebrations that go with it by drawing the image displayed below which can be used as a mod 3 graph!

Start at node 0, for each digit D of the number, move along D black arrows (for digit 0 do not move at all), and as you pass from one digit to the next, move along a single white arrow.

For example, let n = 325, Start at node 0, move along 3 black arrows(to node 0), then 1 white arrow(to node 0), then since the next digit is 2 move along 2 black arrows (to node 2), then 1 white arrow (to node 2), and finally 5 black arrows(to node 1). Finishing at node 1 shows that the remainder on dividing 325 is 1.

If you try this for a number that is divisible by 3, say 9234, you will always end up in node 0. Therefore, this "div-a" can be used to test divisibility by 3. 
I want to know wether it's necessary to have the three yellow loops(representing flames)  or can I do away with them all together and still perform mod 3 .(BTW : Div-a in Hindi means earthen lamp)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do away with it, with or without the yellow loop,which is a self loop ,you end up with the same solution.

As why does the method work:

Notice that $$10 \equiv 1 \mod 3$$

and hence $$\sum_{k} a_k10^k \equiv \sum_{k} a_k \mod 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Yellow Loops (flames)can be done away with as after traversing thesee loops, one would end up at the same node . But they lend a nice shape and significance to the image.